# Parrot Security does not save progress

Tags: linux, debian

I recently downloaded Parrot Security and installed it on my 64 GB USB drive. It worked fine and I’ve done some stuff and then shut down my computer. When I open my computer again nothing saved. It keeps happening when I shut down my computer and open it.

Comment: What's parrot security? A live linux ISO? If you're running live they won't usually automatically save anything

Comment: I've downloaded it on my computer and then when i launched it i press live

Comment: You need to create a live persistent USB.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying what you're really done, but apparently parrot's a Debian based OS that has a (rather large 3.6GB) [hybrid ISO to download](https://www.parrotsec.org/download-full.fx).

[FYI They recommend the [Etcher image writer](https://etcher.io/) for making bootable flash devices. And it's a rolling release based on Debian Testing, stability may be an issue.]

So if you are just running a live Debian system from a read-only ISO it won't save any changes. You need to enable persistence, or just install Parrot to a writeable drive - usually a hard drive/SSD. That would let you update it easier (since it is rolling), without eating a lot of ram with a live `apt-get update` every boot.